# undefined behavior of switch

Tags: c

Given the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=1;
    switch(a)
    {   int b=20;
        case 1: 
            printf("b is %d\n",b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("b is %d\n",b);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What do you think can be value of `b` in both of these `printf` statements? Of course, it is not 20.

Comment: Undefined behavior is exactly that: undefined.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ the code is ill-formed. Case-label `1` crosses initialization of `b`.
In C99 it is valid but invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: This is correct. If you use -Wall, gcc will complain about this.

Comment: This is a C question. That's not correct in C. C has no notion of "ill-formed" either. Damn small differences between these languages :)

Comment: @Johannes : This question was tagged C++ when I saw it.

Comment: @Prasoon alright now your answer is correct, I think :) I +1'ed it.

Comment: if within a switch every statement must be attached with some case then int b=20;will not be executed??

Comment: I don't really get you. You would be having some unspecified value in `b` because the `name`(`b`) is seen by the compiler (so the code gets compiled in C) but the initialization isn't.

Comment: u mean to say compiler allocates memory for b but value is not initialised.